# Access url in routeProvider in AngularJs 1

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am using AngularJs#1.3.8 with **ngRoute** injected in my main module. So, giving the current route:

```
.when('/users', {
                    templateUrl : 'template.html',
                    controller: 'Users',
                    controllerAs : 'Users',
                    resolve: {
                        function (userService) {
                            return userService.initModuleRoles('/users', ['R-USERS']);
                        }
                    }
```

In the service method **initModuleRoles** the first parameter: '/users' can be replace with non hard coded variable ? (something like $route.url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass params to your resolve:

```js
    .when('/users', {
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      controller: 'Users',
      controllerAs: 'Users',
      resolve: {
        lazy: ['userService','$location', function(userService,$location) {
          return userService.initModuleRoles($location.url(), ['R-USERS']);
        }]
      }
    });
```

Comment: so who is $myVar ?

Comment: @que1326, anything you want it to be, in our case `$state`. Why the down vote?

Comment: I didn't down vote your answer. $state belongs to ui.router, I am using ngRoute...

Comment: @que1326, in that case you can get the current route object with `$route.current` or simply the `url` `$location.url()`, edited the code above.

Comment: Thank you very much...for some reasson this didn't work in first place, I tried again and works, thanks a lot sir !